# How to change Picasso to Glide in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a activity with Textview and Imageview. I used to Picasso to retrieve image from Firebase Database . I am using Recyclerview  and Firebase and backend. I want to change the imageview to Gifimage view. Picasso dose't support Gifimageview so I want to change Picasso to Glide. How to apply Glide in this activity. Please help me. Sorry for my bad english.
This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_sub);

    

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.LanguageSubToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chapters");


    if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }




    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    MCC = database.getReference("LanguageJavaSub");


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_LanguageSub);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));


    if (getIntent() != null)
        categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");
    if (!categoryId.isEmpty() && categoryId != null) {
        loadListThrillerSubModel(categoryId);
    }
}

private void loadListThrillerSubModel(String categoryId) {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<computerSubModel, computerViewHolder>(computerSubModel.class,

            R.layout.language_items,
            computerViewHolder.class,
            MCC.orderByChild("menuid").equalTo(categoryId)) {



        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(computerViewHolder viewHolder, final computerSubModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.thrillername.setText(model.getTitle());

            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.image1);


            final computerSubModel local = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {


                    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(LanguageSubActivity.this, LanguageVideoActivity.class);
                    detailsIntent.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(detailsIntent);
                }
            });


        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use this -->

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.sample_gif).into(imageView);
```

or

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(imageView);
```

and yes also add dependencies:

build.gradle file implementation

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

or :

```
Glide.with(getContext()) //use getApplicationContext() or getContext()
.load(model.getImage())
.into(viewHolder.image1)
.asGif();
```

getApplicationContext() : Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of).

getApplicationContext() or getContext() are the inbuilt method in android no need to define whole implementation in code

Comment: Also have to add dependecies to build.gradle file

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

Comment: No. I get this answer - Glide.with(getContext()) - But in my code how can I define (getContext) method

Comment: prasin see my edit...if you still didnt get answer let me know

Comment: I can retrive jpeg image in this methode with out .asGif. .asGif shows Error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Glide` instead of `Picasso` as below:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(imageView)
```

Gradle dependencies as below:-

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

In your code, you can replace your Picasso code with Glide as below:

**Your Picasso code:**

```
Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.image1);
```

**Use Glide code:**

```
 Glide.with(viewHolder.getContext())
                    .load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.image1)
```

For more info please check [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html)

Comment: you can get `viewHolder.getContext()`

Comment: updated my answer please check which explains how you can get the context

Answer (score 0):

For using Glide,

1st add library in Gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

you can find newset version in [here link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

2nd change code where you want.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("image(GIF) url...")
    .into(imageView)
    .asGif();
```

for your example,

change this part

```
 Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.image1);
```

to

```
Glide.with(getContext())
    .load(model.getImage())
    .into(viewHolder.image1)
    .asGif();
```

P.s] check [this docs](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html) for more options

Comment: Thanks bro. But in my code how can I define (getContext) method

Comment: for exampele, in Activity, `MainActivity.this` and in fragment, `getActivity()` use that